# Catch moment when two asynchronous functions running in parallel are both done executing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have two independent asynchronous functions running. I also get the expected results on both functions. My code chunk looks like this:

```
asyncFunc1(arg1A, arg2A, function(result){
  console.log(result);
});

asyncFunc2(arg1B, arg2B, function(result2){
  console.log(result2);
})
```

As can be visually observed, one function returns result earlier than the other. Is there a way that I can catch the moment when both async functions finish their executions and both result and result2 are available?

Any help would be very much apprecited!

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, so both functions will never execute at the same time, if that is what you're asking

Comment: @Isaac I don't think that's what he's asking, he just wants a callback that will be run after both finish, but he doesn't know which order they'll finish.

Comment: I think you need to use _Promises_ for this.

Comment: in this case you have to set a setInterval to check 2 flags which when become true, you clear the timer and you should have 2 results. Or you can try http://dpaste.com/39E1GPF/

Comment: Hi! Isaac is right. I want to run a callback after both functions finish. @Isaac , can you help me on how to use `Promises` on this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AamirAfridi . That in http://dpaste.com/39E1GPF/ is what I also did before trying this one. However, that method takes a significant execution time (especially for large dbs) compared with running those two functions in parallel. Is there something else that you can further suggest? Thank you!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var numFinished = 0;
var bothFinished = function()
{
    console.log('both functions have returned');
}

asyncFunc1(arg1A, arg2A, function(result){
  console.log(result);
  (++numFinished == 2) && bothFinished();
});

asyncFunc2(arg1B, arg2B, function(result2){
  console.log(result2);
  (++numFinished == 2) && bothFinished();
})
```

Comment: This is a rather elegant solution.

Comment: wooooah!  It worked! Thank you, @Gio! This has been very helpful! It's exactly what I needed! I had been trying to debug this for almost 4 hours now. >.< Thank you very much!